# Regex to create two capture groups, where the second captures multiple times

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

My test string is

```
thread_id=1152236, geo_locality.nomv="Seattle|||San Francisco|||Chicago", user_reference_count=0
```

Is it possible to have *one* regex to have *two* capture groups, where the second capture group will capture multiple times?

I want the first capture group to capture `geo_locality` (without hardcoding) and the second capture group to capture `Seattle`, `San Francisco`, and `Chicago`.

The closest I got was

```
(?<key>\w+)\.nomv="(?<val>.+?)(?=\|\|\||")
```

https://regex101.com/r/wmxg4x/1

Except the `val` capturing group also needs to capture the other cities.

Comment: Regex alone cannot replace, eg `Seattle|||San Francisco|||Chicago` to `Seattle,San Francisco,Chicago` unless you first extract that group and then call `replace` on it in whatever language you're working with.

Comment: No, I need second capturing group to capture each city individually kind of like `(?<val>[^|]+)`.

Comment: Remember that, as regex101 says, `A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data`. In the languages I know of, you'll need a separate group for each city to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: So, you're saying I have to do this in two regex? That's easy, but I was hoping to do it one since the program I'm running wants to use one. Thanks though.

Comment: Just capture the whole delimited string in 1 capture group. Then split that on the delimiter.

Comment: Either use two regex (or one regex and a `split` of some sort), or use one regex in which each possible repeated `VAL_#` is specified explicitly: https://regex101.com/r/wmxg4x/2 It's pretty ugly, I'd prefer the first option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the regex flavor at play.

1. Using `\G` to continue at the end of the previous match with a PCRE

   ```
   (?<key>\w+)\.nomv="|(?!^)(?<=\G)(?<val>.+?)(?:\|\|\||")
   ```

   [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/InwFNX/1)

   The `\G` anchor can be a bit arcane and truly magical at the same time.

Explanation:

- `(?<key>\w+)\.nomv="|` the key and literal in the 1st alternation act as a start anchor
- The `\G` anchor asserts the position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

  - to exclude the start of the string I've added `(?!^)` to prevent matches before `nom="`).
  - `(?<=\G)` so, we can only continue if there was a match before
  - `(?<val>.+?)` captures each city block as required
  - `(?:\|\|\||")` the non-capturing group is simply used to move the cursor forward

---

2. Using Captures with .NET

   ```
   (?<_KEY_1>\w+)\.nomv="(?:(?<_VAL_1>.+?)(?:\|\|\||"))*
   ```

   [Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C_KEY_1%3E%5Cw%2B%29%5C.nomv%3D%22%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3C_VAL_1%3E.%2B%3F%29%28%3F%3A%5C%7C%5C%7C%5C%7C%7C%22%29%29*&i=page_name%3D%22xxx.com%22%2C%20page_type%3Dother%2C%20thread_id%3D1152236%2C%20geo_locality.nomv%3D%22Seattle%7C%7C%7CSan%20Francisco%7C%7C%7CChicago%22%2C%20user_reference_count%3D0%2C)

   This is not a real challenge for .NET. Just add a group around and a quantifier, and let `(?<val>)` match multiple times. Then, get the values from the [Captures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture(v=vs.110).aspx).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with if supported a positive lookbehind `(?<=`

[`(?<_KEY_1>\w+)(?=\.nomv=")|(?<_VAL_1>(?<=\.nomv=")[A-Za-z ]+|(?<=\|\|\|)[A-Za-z ]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/VqPHBV/1/)

**Explanation**

- `(?<_KEY_1>` Named capture group

  - `\w+` Match one or more times a word character
- `)` Close named capture group
- `(?=\.nomv=")` Positive lookahead that asserts that what follows is `.nomv="`
- `|` Or
- `(?<_VAL_1>` Named capture group

  - `(?<=\.nomv=")` Positive lookbehind that assert that what is on the left is  `.nomv=`
  - `[A-Za-z ]+` Match an uppercase, lowercase or whitespace
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=\|\|\|)` Positive lookbehind that assert that what is on the left is `|||`
  - `[A-Za-z ]+` Match an uppercase, lowercase or whitespace
- `)` Close named capture group

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `(?<_KEY_1>\w+)\.nomv="(?<_VAL_1>(.+?\|\|\|)+.+)"`.

One thing to note is that inside capturing group `_VAL_1` there can be some more capturing groups, but `_VAL_1` is what you need.

See [DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/wmxg4x/3)